# Errors appearing while running Spring MVC app

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, jboss7.x

I am working on Spring MVC app using Spring MVC 4.0, Hibernate 4, Jboss 7.1.1. Following jars I am using:

[image]

Following is my dispatcher servlet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd     
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd"> 

    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.example.scm" />
    <tx:annotation-driven/>
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="jndiDataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiName" value="java:/MySqlDS" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="jndiDataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.example.scm"></property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="loginService" class="com.example.scm.services.LoginService"/>
    <bean id="loginDao" class="com.example.scm.dao.LoginDao"/>
</beans>
```

Following is my web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
    <display-name>Example</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>route</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>route</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

On running app, it shows exceptions:

```
07:03:49,951 SEVERE [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-27) Context initialization failed: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'loginDao': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.example.scm.dao.LoginDao.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/route-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.addAnnotatedClass(Ljava/lang/Class;)Lorg/hibernate/cfg/Configuration;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:292) [spring-beans-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1185) [spring-beans-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537) [spring-beans-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475) [spring-beans-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304) [spring-beans-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) [spring-beans-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300) [spring-beans-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195) [spring-beans-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:700) [spring-beans-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760) [spring-context-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482) [spring-context-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:643) [spring-webmvc-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:606) [spring-webmvc-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:657) [spring-webmvc-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:525) [spring-webmvc-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:466) [spring-webmvc-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136) [spring-webmvc-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:242) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1202) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:952) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:188) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_75]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.example.scm.dao.LoginDao.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/route-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.addAnnotatedClass(Ljava/lang/Class;)Lorg/hibernate/cfg/Configuration;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:508) [spring-beans-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87) [spring-beans-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289) [spring-beans-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
    ... 30 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/route-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.addAnnotatedClass(Ljava/lang/Class;)Lorg/hibernate/cfg/Configuration;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1553) [spring-beans-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539) [spring-beans-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475) [spring-beans-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304) [spring-beans-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) [spring-beans-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300) [spring-beans-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195) [spring-beans-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014) [spring-beans-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:957) [spring-beans-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:855) [spring-beans-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:480) [spring-beans-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
    ... 32 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.addAnnotatedClass(Ljava/lang/Class;)Lorg/hibernate/cfg/Configuration;
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.scanPackages(LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.java:280) [spring-orm-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:407) [spring-orm-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1612) [spring-beans-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1549) [spring-beans-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
    ... 42 more

07:03:49,973 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/sco]] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-27) StandardWrapper.Throwable: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'loginDao': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.example.scm.dao.LoginDao.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/route-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.addAnnotatedClass(Ljava/lang/Class;)Lorg/hibernate/cfg/Configuration;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:292) [spring-beans-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1185) [spring-beans-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537) [spring-beans-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475) [spring-beans-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304) [spring-beans-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) [spring-beans-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300) [spring-beans-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195) [spring-beans-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:700) [spring-beans-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760) [spring-context-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482) [spring-context-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:643) [spring-webmvc-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:606) [spring-webmvc-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:657) [spring-webmvc-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:525) [spring-webmvc-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:466) [spring-webmvc-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136) [spring-webmvc-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:242) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1202) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:952) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:188) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_75]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.example.scm.dao.LoginDao.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/route-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.addAnnotatedClass(Ljava/lang/Class;)Lorg/hibernate/cfg/Configuration;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:508) [spring-beans-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87) [spring-beans-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289) [spring-beans-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
    ... 30 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/route-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.addAnnotatedClass(Ljava/lang/Class;)Lorg/hibernate/cfg/Configuration;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1553) [spring-beans-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539) [spring-beans-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475) [spring-beans-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304) [spring-beans-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) [spring-beans-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300) [spring-beans-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195) [spring-beans-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014) [spring-beans-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:957) [spring-beans-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:855) [spring-beans-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:480) [spring-beans-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
    ... 32 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.addAnnotatedClass(Ljava/lang/Class;)Lorg/hibernate/cfg/Configuration;
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.scanPackages(LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.java:280) [spring-orm-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:407) [spring-orm-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1612) [spring-beans-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1549) [spring-beans-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
    ... 42 more

07:03:49,995 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/sco].[route]] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-27) Allocate exception for servlet route: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.addAnnotatedClass(Ljava/lang/Class;)Lorg/hibernate/cfg/Configuration;
```

Following is my controller class:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = {"/", "/login"})
public class LoginController {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory
            .getLogger(LoginController.class);

    @Autowired
    LoginService loginService;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String login() {
        return "Login";
    }
}
```

Controller class connects to dao via service class. Following is my service class:

```
@Service("loginService")
public class LoginService {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory
            .getLogger(LoginService.class);

    @Autowired
    private LoginDao loginDao;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure your classpath is correct? The method is contained in hibernate-core-4.2.16.Final, so this should be no problem. Btw: Any good reason you are using two different versions of hibernate-jpa?

Comment: @DirkLachowski, Thanks for telling. Which version of hibernate-jpa should I keep?

Comment: Please replace org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder instead of org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean. and try

Comment: @VishalSuri Are you get same error message after change sessionFactory class?

Comment: Yes, I am getting same error message after changing sessionfactory class. My be it is a classpath issue. How can we set classpath in spring mvc app?

Comment: @VishalSuri What is it in your application-context.xml? Or you use only dispatcher servlet?

Comment: @herry, I am using only dispatcher servlet.

Comment: @herry, I have a struts application deployed on same server. Can this cause any problem?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are using same variable names in the Service class & Dao class as mentioned in the dispatcher servlet

```
<bean id="loginService" class="com.example.scm.services.LoginService"/>
<bean id="loginDao" class="com.example.scm.dao.LoginDao"/>
```

Comment: Can anyone please help ?

Comment: Can you post your Controller class where you are using Dao & Service?

Comment: I have posted my controller and service classes.